# Function Pointers, In STM32 and how do i understand these Type Handles?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, stm32, hal

I'm getting a very confusing error as I may be making a small mistake with the phrasing or the type handles or it could be a more complicated problem

Basically I want to create this funciton `Buf_IO(HAL_StatusTypeDef IO)` that can take one of two inputs either
`HAL_SPI_Transmit`
or
`HAL_SPI_Recieve`

these are both defined as

```cpp
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_SPI_Transmit/*or Recieve*/(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout)
```

so in my code i have defined my function pointer as follows

```cpp
HAL_StatusTypeDef (FuncPtr*)(SPI_HandleTypeDef*, uint8_t*, uint16_t, uint32_t) = IO;
```

where IO is the argument to my function
however for some reason i get the error

```
invalid conversion from 'HAL_StatusTypeDef (*)(SPI_HandleTypeDef*, uint8_t*, uint16_t, uint32_t)' {aka 'HAL_StatusTypeDef (*)(__SPI_HandleTypeDef*, unsigned char*, short unsigned int, long unsigned int)'} to 'void (*)(SPI_HandleTypeDef*, uint8_t*, uint16_t, uint32_t)' {aka 'void (*)(__SPI_HandleTypeDef*, unsigned char*, short unsigned int, long unsigned int)'}
```

for clarity this is how i have declared the funtion in the .cpp file

```cpp
void MAX_Interface::Buf_IO(HAL_StatusTypeDef IO)
{
    HAL_StatusTypeDef (FuncPtr*)(SPI_HandleTypeDef*, uint8_t*, uint16_t, uint32_t) = IO;
    uint8_t* buf_ptr = (uint8_t*) &OBuf;

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, h_CS, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    FuncPtr(h_SPI, buf_ptr, 3, 100);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, h_CS, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}
```

I do understand that i may be overcomplicating this as I have previously written just two different functions for transmitting an receiving but I'm looking to make my code more concise and also learn a bit in the process so feel free to suggest a more elegant solution if you can think of one?

Comment: You really DON'T want to do this.  In most embedded systems, you at least one function for transmit and one for receive; you don't make a parent function that calls them based on an argument.  Just call the appropriate transmit or receive function directly.  You are making the code more complex, and complex code is more defect prone.

Comment: I recommend copying the code that "opens" the SPI port to both the transmit and receive functions.  It's not enough code to warrant a separate function (remember, functions have overhead and the content should be a lot more than the overhead).  The compiler should be able to optimize the statements for opening and closing the SPI port.  If you must create those functions, then remind the compiler that you'd like them inline.

Comment: somewhere out there the function pointer return type gets swapped out for `void`

Comment: Not sure why you're expecting an assignment of a type matching the return type of the function to the function pointer is expected to work. This looks to me though as if a template function may be beneficial here: `template<class F> void Buf_IO(F f) { ... f(h_SPI, buf_ptr, 3, 100); ... }` could work; it should allow you to use `myObject.Buf_IO(HAL_SPI_Transmit); myObject.Buf_IO(HAL_SPI_Receive);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, you should use the [`using`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) directive to define the function signature. `using` is similar to `typedef` in C, but makes things much more readable.

```cpp
using IO = HAL_StatusTypeDef(SPI_HandleTypeDef*, uint8_t*, uint16_t, uint32_t);
```

Note, that IO is now the alias of the function signature itself, not a pointer to the function.

Now, in your function you use it as `IO*` to specify that the parameter is a function pointer:

```cpp
void MAX_Interface::Buf_IO(IO* funcPtr)
{
    uint8_t* buf_ptr = (uint8_t*) &OBuf;

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, h_CS, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    funcPtr(h_SPI, buf_ptr, 3, 100);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, h_CS, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}
```